# How can I install ubuntu touch on HTC Desire 300 ?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

when and how I can install ubuntu touch on HTC Desire 300 ?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment Ubuntu only released development version on Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4. http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install

There is some tutorial on how to install Ubuntu phone OS on some specific mobile phone but I don't know any tutorial for HTC Desire 300.